# Returning values form function in IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I try to learn IONIC 5.
I use native geolocation to return latitude and longitude.
From this function i need to retrive lat and long and then make available to sent to the server trough a form.

```
geolocate()
   {
         this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
         let position = {
           latitude: resp.coords.latitude,
           longitude: resp.coords.longitude
         }
         return position;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
  }
```

using this other function

```
login(form: NgForm) {
        this.geolocate();
        this.authService.login(form.value.email, form.value.password, this.latitude, this.longitude).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.alertService.presentToast("Logged In");
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            () => {
                this.dismissLogin();
                this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('');
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async login(form: NgForm) {
        let res = await this.geolocate();
        this.latitude = res.latitude;
        this.longitude = res.longitude;
        this.authService.login(form.value.email, form.value.password, this.latitude, this.longitude).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.alertService.presentToast("Logged In");
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            () => {
                this.dismissLogin();
                this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('');
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: geolocate is an asynchronus funcntion so you can access property latitude because the return of this function will return the null object.

Comment: `geolocate()` should have a `return` at the beginning of the first line in its block: `return this.geolocation.getCurrentPo...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the call to `getCurrentPosition()`:

```
geolocate() {

return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
     return {
       latitude: resp.coords.latitude,
       longitude: resp.coords.longitude
     };
   }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting location', error);
   });
}
```

Then, await the result and store it in a variable to use it in the next function call.

```
async login(form: NgForm) {
    const coords = await this.geolocate();

this.authService.login(form.value.email, form.value.password, coords.latitude, coords.longitude).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.alertService.presentToast("Logged In");
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
            this.dismissLogin();
            this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('');
        }
    );
}
```